# GA4 account that is different then Firebase Analytics setup in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am trying to record screen_views to another GA4 account that isn't the default Firebase that is linked from the .json file.  Is there a way to do this in React Native for iOS and Android?

Comment: Are you using any React Native Firebase library?

Comment: Sure, whatever can get the job done for another GA4 account.

Comment: I am using it, but I want to use another GA4 account which isn't possible with the default one for the library.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, there's a capability to send events into an additional destination, but it's definitely not easy, conventional or comfortable.

First of all, when you do native (or react native) tracking, you normally use a Firebase Analytics SDK. That SDK, as the whole of Google Analytics, is not quite a premium enterprise analytics product, so it basically offers a bit more over what would typically be considered as MVP. When you initialize an instance of the SDK, you can actually only use one Firebase account as a destination. You can't use the SDK to send data to more than one Firebase account. On top of that, when you link a GA4 account to the FB account, you can only link one GA4 account to one FB account. Very basic logic.

GA4, however, has its own API for custom data injections. It's called the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4). You could, of course, just generate network requests from the app hitting the endpoint as the API suggests. There are nuances for sure, however. GA wants you to supply client ids, session ids and stuff like that for the data to be complete.

Measurement protocol is quite unpleasant to use though since it's now dealing with raw http requests that have to have a strict structure and now suddenly you have to manually set fields that the Firebase SDK would typically abstract from you. And this kind of tracking will likely spawn unexpected sessions/users in the destination analytics, so the destination analytics owners have to be prepared for that, or guide you to how to set those key ids.

Comment: So there is no library to handle this situation? It seems there should be documentation or some sort somewhere if this was possible.  Who wouldn't want to collect data to multiple accounts, I already have the Firebase SDK setup for the customer and analytics.

Comment: There are some libraries to use GA's MP for sure, at least in the npm space (not sure about react native libs), but you have to watch out. The library has to be freshly updated. Most of them are stale now cuz they're still using Universal GA's measurement protocol, and GAU is what Google replaced with GA4, so that won't work. I know, a lot of corps have had very similar issues. But don't forget, Firebase/GA is a free product essentially. And it's best among free products. People can either hack around to make it do more, or pay up for premium products.

Comment: I need to mention that most of the corps solve these issues on a much-much later stage. So they join FB to GA4, then they set up autoexport from GA4 to BQ, then they use whatever ETL tool they want to ETL the data from BQ to whatever third party destinations including other GA4 accounts and whatnot. Vast majority of GA's shortcomings are fixed in ETL.